# Angular datatables sorting issue

Tags: angularjs, sorting, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using this example https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/bootstrapIntegration to configure my data tables. The problem is it won't sort the date and `double` price.

So far I try to sort the date but failed. I did find a lot of answers but no one is working.

My javascript

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
  .withOption('order', [0, 'desc']);

$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
  { targets: 0, type: 'date' } 
];
```

My html

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" class="row-border hover"></table
```

I also tried something like

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
  DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).withOption('type', 'date'),
];
```

And I did tried change the `date` to `dd/MM/yy` but not working. My date in column is showed as `23/03/19`

Answer (score 0):

DataTables' date sorting is based on `Date.parse()` so any not-parseable date (or timestamp) will break the sorting.

A date in north european notation ala `23/03/19` parses to `NaN`, and there you have your problem. You can parse the date in a `render()` callback :

```
DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).renderWidth(function(data) {
  data = data.split('/')
  return Date.parse(data[1]+'-'+data[0]+'-'+data[2]).valueOf()
})
```

or you can use a custom sorting plugin like `date-eu` -> **https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-eu**